# Dynamically size UItextView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` in a `UITableViewCell`. I'm trying to dynamically size the `textView`.

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    [self.myTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.myTableView endUpdates];
}
```

After every char I input, the whole view jumps to the top, then jumps right back down to where I was at.

The solution for that, is probably to take away `begin/endUpdates`. When I do that, the `textView` sizes itself correctly, but the cell's height doesn't change.

> **Qustion:**
>
> How can I make the `textView` **and** the `tableVIewCell` dynamically size itself?

Comment: How do you put UITextView inside a UITableView?Can you edit the question with that as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload only that particular cell in which the TextView is added.
Try this

```
[self.myTableView beginUpdates];
 [self.myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [self.myTableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: It removes the text every time I enter a new line. My question is not about reloading tableViews, it's about dynamically sizing textViews